# Retrieving underlying exception from SqlDataReader for INSERT statment

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am executing a SQL insert statement e.g.

```
INSERT INTO Table (fk1, value1) OUTPUT inserted.pk VALUES ('fkv1', 'v1');
```

where "pk" is an auto incremented key value, as:

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The foreign key is in conflict with the parent table, and the reader.HasRows() reflects this, but how can I retrieve the actual exception object that was thrown with the error description?  If you remove the "OUTPUT" statement, it throws the exception fine, but with that statement in there, it swallows the error, and just returns that "HasRows" == false.

I can see the error using the debugger under the "Results View" property, but how can I get this value in code?

Sql Server 2008r2
.NET 4.0

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

This call does not throw an exception.  The only indication that it has not completed successfully is that "HasRows" is false.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding this code with a try/catch block?

Comment: Make sure to `catch(ExceptionType ex)`, to get the exception's information.

Answer (score 4):

```
try
{
   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   string errorMessage = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                         "Exception Type: {0}, Message: {1}{2}", 
                         ex.GetType(),
                         ex.Message,
                         ex.InnerException == null ? String.Empty : 
                         String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                                      " InnerException Type: {0}, Message: {1}",
                                      ex.InnerException.GetType(),
                                      ex.InnerException.Message));

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a piece of sql which is generating an exception and yet the try catch is not catching it - it is so weird!

Here is the code

```
try
{
    // Run the SQL statement, and then get the returned rows to the DataReader.

    SqlDataReader MyDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();

    //note AT THIS POINT there is an exception in MyDataReader
    //if I view MyDataReader in Watch I see this in base->ResultsView->base
    //Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'lwang' to data type int
    //and errors count is 1 but there is no exception catch!!

    int iRow = 0;
    if (MyDataReader.HasRows)
    {
        int iCol = 0;
        while (MyDataReader.Read())
        {

            //dt.Load(MyDataReader);
            List<String> strFields = new List<String>();

            for (int iField = 0; iField < MyDataReader.FieldCount; iField++)
            {
                strReturn = strReturn + MyDataReader[iField] + ",";
                strFields.Add(MyDataReader[iField].ToString());
            }
            DataRows.Add(strFields);
            iRow++;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //no exception is caught in this case!!  This code is never reached!!
    strError = "An error occurred getting the data table: " + MyCommand.CommandText + " " + ex.ToString();
    throw new Exception(strError);
    return (DataRows);
}
finally
{
    Connection.Close();
}
    return (DataRows);
}
```

In case it helps here is the sql being executed
The sql being executed is:

> select 
>   hec_recommendation.RecID, hec_recommendation.UtilityID, hec_recommendation.CatID, hec_recommendation.Condition, hec_recommendation.RecommendationText, hec_recommendation.Active, hec_recommendation.Ordinal, hec_recommendation.StartDate, hec_recommendation.EndDate, hec_recommendation.CreateDate, hec_recommendation.CreatedByID, hec_recommendation.ModifyDate, hec_recommendation.ModifyByID
>   from hec_recommendation, hec_utility, hec_reccategory  where
>   hec_recommendation.utilityid = hec_utility.id and
>   hec_recommendation.catid = hec_reccategory.catid and
>   hec_reccategory.utilityid = hec_utility.utilityid and 
>   hec_utility.utilityId = 'lwang'

Comment: If you have a question, please post a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)